# PDO - query not returning results - output is empty and not sure why

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Trying to perform my first simple PDO query.  Nothing is being output.

The fields in the mySQL table are indeed full of content, they are not blank.
Connecting to the db is working.

My output is as follows:

```
Connected to database.
dfsdfs 1object(PDO)#2 (0) { }
```

These code lines are not outputting:

```
        PDO::errorInfo()
    echo "Performing a select: <br>";
    print_r($row);
```

These code lines are also not outputting:

```
    <h2><?php echo $row['articleTitle']; ?></h2>
    <?php echo $row['articleBody']; ?>
```

My code:

```
<?php

/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'removed';
/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'removed';
/*** mysql password ***/
$password = 'removed';
function testdb_connect ($hostname, $username, $password){
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=removed", $username, $password);
return $dbh;
}

try {
$dbh = testdb_connect ($hostname, $username, $password);
echo 'Connected to database';
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
$dbh = testdb_connect ($hostname, $username, $password);

$id=$_GET[id];
echo 'dfsdfs '.$id;
var_dump($dbh);
$sql="SELECT * FROM 'radiologyArticles' WHERE 'id' = :id";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();
    if (!$stmt) {
      echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
      print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
    }
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {  
echo "Performing a select: <br>";
print_r($row);                                  
?>
<section>
    <header>
        <h2><?php echo $row['articleTitle']; ?></h2>
    </header>
    <p>
    <?php echo $row['articleBody']; ?>
    </p>
</section>
<?php
}
// close the PDO connection
$link = null;
?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: Why 2x of `$dbh = testdb_connect ($hostname, $username, $password);`?

Comment: Plus this `$link = null;` should most likely be `$dbh = null;` and quote `$id=$_GET[id];` --- `$id=$_GET['id'];`

Comment: Thanks Fred.  Appreciated  .. now fixed

Comment: Plus, if it was Jeroen's answer, do accept as the correct answer, which seems to be the case, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you don't see any errors, but this line is wrong:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM 'radiologyArticles' WHERE 'id' = :id";
```

You should not use quotes (single or double) for table- or column names. If you need to quote them (in case of reserved words for example), you need backticks:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `radiologyArticles` WHERE `id` = :id";
```

To make sure that PHP throws an exception when it encounters a problem, you could change your connetion string to:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=removed", $username, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
```

Comment: I thought I'd be doing a good thing by adding "while under development", since errors should not be thrown while a site is ready/LIVE.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I un-did you edit because I don't really agree with it: I always have PDO throw exceptions, I just handle them differently while developing or when in production. Sorry :-)

Comment: Ok, not a problem. Yet, wouldn't `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` throw any errors that a user shouldn't be seeing?

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, it throws an exception. If you catch it you can handle it any way you like.

Comment: Ok, got it and noted. grazie

Comment: @Fred-ii- you are confusing throwing errors and displaying them.  While, Jeroen, catching has nothing to do with this matter. It's all about displaying, not catching.

Comment: @YourCommonSense In this case it is about displaying, so an uncaught exception is all the OP needs but on a live site you don't want that as mentioned by Fred-ii-. Note that my comment about catching the exception was not directed at the OP. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Fred and Jeroen, after both of your exceptional answers the code is now working.  Not sure which caused the error.  But it all works now.  Thanks

Comment: Catching simply shouldn't be used to prevent displaying, and shouldn't have been mentioned in this context - that's all I wanted to say.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Ahhh, I get it. The reason I brought it up was that my answer was edited and I didn't agree with it. That evolved in a small discussion over exceptions that wasn't really related to the OP's problem...

Comment: I'll take all the heat on this one ;-)